# Find the components of this tensor

Tags: tensor-products

It is give to me a tensor type (2,0) and a tensor type (1,0), that is, a vector. Now i need to find a tensor of type (1,1), as follow:
$$X^{\mu v} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & -1\\ 
-1 & 0 &  3& 2\\ 
 -1&  1& 0 & 0\\ 
 -2&  1& 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ V^{\mu} = (-1,2,0,2)$$
$$X^{\mu}_{v}?$$

I am a little stuck. Normally i do not see tensor as matrix. What i would do normally is find the metric tensor and so lower the indices of the first tensor, but it is not the case here. What do you recommend?

Comment: You cannot "find the metric tensor". You must be given the metric tensor.

Comment: Yes, but it was not give to me, that is the whole problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like $\color{red}{X^{\mu\nu}}$, the tensors $\color{limegreen}{X^\mu_{\:\nu}}$, $\color{blue}{X^{\:\mu}_\nu}$ and $\color{orange}{X_{\mu\nu}}$ look like square matrices if you write them in components. Note for asymmetric $\color{red}{X^{\mu\nu}}$ this list includes two $(1,\,1)$ tensors, the green and blue ones. The difference between these four tensors is actually in how those components transform under a general coordinate transformation. They're also related via metric tensors viz.$$\color{red}{X^{\mu\nu}}=g^{\rho\nu}\color{green}{X^\mu_{\:\rho}}=g^{\mu\rho}\color{blue}{X^{\:\nu}_\rho}=g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}\color{orange}{X_{\rho\sigma}}.$$I'll leave it to you to write down some more such equations, including those that use the index-lowering metric tensor.

Comment: Hi. I was aware of the necessity of the metric tensor to find the components, but i was not able to find it. Curiosity, your answer makes me think that we could find the metric tensor components by multiply $V_{\mu}V^{\mu}$. I ended find it:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  -2&  0&-2 \\ 
 -2&  4& 0 & 4\\ 
 0&0  &  0&0 \\ 
-2 &  4&0  &4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Being symmetric, i think this is a good signal that i am going by the right place, do you think this is ok?

Comment: @GabrielaDaSilva No, you're on completely the wrong track. Whereas $V^\mu V^\nu$'s components fill a square matrix, $V_\mu V^\mu=V^\mu V^\nu g_{\mu\nu}$ is actually a scalar. The metric tensor depends on the coordinate syatem and manifold, but since you're working with $4$-dimensional examples I'm guessing you're thinking about special relativity, and its metric tensors in Cartesian coordinates are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Lorentzian_metrics_from_relativity).